# How to manage multiple articles posts in Angular using Angular Routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm trying to create a website using Angular which has many articles and whenever I press on an article it goes to a new URL using routing.

[image: 1]

For this I have created a new Article component and my `app-routing.module.ts` looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'article1', component: ArticlesComponent },
  { path: 'article2', component: ArticlesComponent },
  { path: 'article3', component: ArticlesComponent },
  { path: 'article4', component: ArticlesComponent },
  { path: 'article5', component: ArticlesComponent },
  { path: 'article6', component: ArticlesComponent },
];
```

I am routing everything to the same component because I don't want to make a new component for each article. How do I display different data on this component depending on the user's click on one of the articles?

Comment: Add variable to your routing (e.g. `:articleId`). Then you can read router variable value in component by `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.articleId` and build custom logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a specific path for articles and declare a path parameter (`:articleId`):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'articles/:articleId', component: ArticlesComponent },
];
```

Then in your `ArticlesComponent` you can get the current article ID from the path using:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map((params: ParamMap) => {
      const articleId = params.get('articleId')
      // fetch the article with that ID and render it
    })
  );
}
```

Example: visiting `yourapp.com/articles/article-1` will pass `"article-1"` as value for the path parameter `:articleId`.

Comment: Let's say if I have too much data on each article and every article don't have same format. In this case using observable paramMap api dosent solve the problem. I want to achieve something like this:  https://www.helpscout.com/blog/